# Is there a difference between "sudo apt-get vim" and "./configure --with-features=huge"?

Tags: installing, linux-debian

I'd like to install VIM via apt-get, but I'm not sure if I get all of its features.

Is there a difference between this, and compiling it from source?

Answer (score 15):

If you look at the options used to build the various packages (in [`debian/rules`](https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim/blob/debian/sid/debian/rules)), you'll see

```
OPTFLAGS+=--with-features=huge

...

NOINTERPFLAGS:=--disable-luainterp
NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-mzschemeinterp
NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-perlinterp
ifeq ($(DEB_VENDOR),Ubuntu)
    NOINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=$(shell python-config --configdir)
else
    NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-pythoninterp
endif
NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-python3interp
NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-rubyinterp
NOINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-tclinterp

ALLINTERPFLAGS:=--enable-luainterp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-mzschemeinterp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-perlinterp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=$(shell python-config --configdir)
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-python3interp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-rubyinterp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-tclinterp
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--with-tclsh=/usr/bin/tclsh

...

CFLAGS_vim-basic:=$(CFLAGS)
CFGFLAGS_vim-basic:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(NOXFLAGS) $(NOINTERPFLAGS)

CFLAGS_vim-tiny:=$(CFLAGS) -DTINY_VIMRC
CFGFLAGS_vim-tiny:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(TINYFLAGS)

CFLAGS_vim-gtk:=$(CFLAGS)
CFGFLAGS_vim-gtk:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(GUIFLAGS) $(GTKFLAGS) $(ALLINTERPFLAGS)

CFLAGS_vim-gnome:=$(CFLAGS)
CFGFLAGS_vim-gnome:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(GUIFLAGS) $(GNOMEFLAGS) $(ALLINTERPFLAGS)

CFLAGS_vim-athena:=$(CFLAGS)
CFGFLAGS_vim-athena:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(GUIFLAGS) $(ATHENAFLAGS) $(ALLINTERPFLAGS)

CFLAGS_vim-nox:=$(CFLAGS)
CFGFLAGS_vim-nox:=$(CFGFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(NOXFLAGS) $(ALLINTERPFLAGS)
```

So:

- all packages except `vim-tiny` gets built with `--with-features=huge`
- `vim-basic` (aka `vim`) has interpreters turned *off*
- the others have options based on frontend, with interpreters turned on.

To pick one:

- If you'd like a barebones Vim, pick `vim-tiny`.
- If you'd like a more full-featured Vim, pick `vim`.
- If you'd like all the features that the packaging allows, but *don't* want GUI (and the dependencies of a GUI), pick `vim-nox`.
- If you'd like a GUI, and but don't want anything to do with GTK, pick `vim-athena`.
- If you'd like a GUI, <strike>and use a GNOME-based desktop environment (GNOME, Unity, Cinnamon, etc.), pick `vim-gnome`</strike> and use a GTK3-based environment (GNOME, Unity, Cinnamon, MATE, etc.), pick `vim-gtk3`.
- If you'd like a GUI, and use a GTK2-based or non-GTK desktop environment (XFCE, LXDE, etc.), pick `vim-gtk`.

Comment: I would like to accept this as the answer, but, when I asked the question, I was unregistered.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy if you registered with another email, you can merge the accounts.

Comment: I registered with the same e-mail, actually. I even got a notification that this answer was posted—but there's no accept-answer checkmark, for some reason.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy at first glance, it seems there's nothing I can do as mod, sorry. You'll need to contact the Stack Exchange team, as given in http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: @muru, what are the benefits of vim-gnome over vim-gtk? Both use libgtk2, the former adds libgnome2: that has to be good for something!

Comment: @RobertSiemer does http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#gui-gnome help?

Comment: @muru Yeah, that is gold!

Comment: Although `:help gui-gnome` is pretty obsolete.  On modern Gnome, there's not much that vim-gnome provides (c.f., [Debian bug #820239](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820239)) which is why I removed it.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed the version you get with `apt-get install vim` doesn't have all the features of a version compiled with  `--with-features=huge`. For example you don't always have options like `+python` or `+lua`.

A good alternative is to use `apt-get install vim-nox` which is much more complete.

Answer (score 5):

`$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk` (or `vim-gnome` if you are on Ubuntu) will get you the most complete Vim with the least effort.

Official packages usually lag a bit so, if you *really* want the latest version, you will have to apply the latest patches and build it yourself.

Be aware, though, that new patches come up every couple of days, so keeping up with upstream needs dedication.

Comment: [pi-rho's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) generally has very up-to-date packages.

Comment: @muru, agreed and recommended. That's the one I used when I was using Ubuntu.